# Existe alguma maneira de especificar o tempo de execução do scroll-behavior: smooth?

Tags: css

A propriedade `scroll-behavior: smooth` permite altera o comportamento do scroll para ficar mais suave.

Exemplo:

```css
#scroll{
   overflow: auto;
   height: 600px;
   width: 100%;
   scroll-behavior: smooth
}

#a, #b {
  height: 600px;
}

#a{
   background-color: red;
}

#b {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll">
  <a href='#b'>Faça o scroll</a>
  <div id='a'></div>
  <div id='b'></div>
</div>
```

Porém, até onde eu percebi, parece propriedade `smooth` já tem seu próprio tempo padrão para executar o scroll suave.

Gostaria de saber se é possível aumentar ou diminuir o tempo da rolagem suave quando usamos `scroll-behavior` **apenas pelo CSS**  - ou seja, sem uso de Javascript.

Comment: Aparentemente essa propriedade ainda esta como [rascunho](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#smooth-scrolling), então quem sabe no futuro surgirá alguma sugestão de implementação, mas isso é só especulação. De qualquer forma controlar isso seria um pouco irritante para o usuário final, a não ser que houvesse um range de limite de tempo, talvez de `0.01s` até `1.0s` (só exemplo).

Answer (score -2):

Olá,

Infelizmente não :/, ainda não temos uma propriedade que informe o tempo de transição pro `scroll-behavior`.
Essa propriedade apenas informa ao browser como será o tipo de "scrollagem" e nada além disso

*Quem sabe futuramente não seja adicionado ao CSS essa feature *